# how to draw a graph with luatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I was compiling the following code to render a graph which I copied from internet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        4 -> { 
          3 -> { 1 -> { 5, " " }, 2,2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 }
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The command I used to compile the code was:

> luatex test.tex

(`test.tex` is the file I used to save the code above)

I got an error showing the picture below:
[image]

Please help me to solve this. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

## [Update]

I changed `luatex` to `lualtex`. But new errors coming.
[image]

## [Update v2]

According to comment from `sergiokapone`, I add a `\usepackage{tikz}` in preamble as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        4 -> { 
          3 -> { 1 -> { 5, " " }, 2,2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 }
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two compiled results still with errors:
[image]

## [Update 3]

Thank  Torbjørn T for your help. How stupid i am!! I forget to save the updated files. However I always save files on linux using vim. but i am using notepad++ on windows for this test. So I forget the saving...

The file has been successfully compiled and produce the following result.
[image]

Thanks again!

Comment: use `lualatex test.tex` ....

Comment: Thanks. but this resulting new errors...

Comment: @alban just add `\usepackage{tikz}` in preamble

Comment: @sergiokapone still not work. I am update the answer with your advice.

Comment: Comment aside: The present version of the `LuaTeX` engine is `1.0.4`, not `0.95`.

Comment: @Bernard I am using texlive 2016, so I just need to update `luatex`?

Comment: @Bernard I think the code should be well compiled with luatex with version greater than 0.54 as stated in the pgfmanual. Am i missed something?

Comment: @alban Your code is successfully compiled after the update (I'm use `TeXLive2016` on Win10). Can you show log-file?

Comment: the error you show in the final image is not from the file where you had added `\usepackage{tikz}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is included in OP's MWE after update

Comment: @sergiokapone yes sorry i was confused by the OPs multiple updates:-)

Comment: please show the log file from lualatex on your updated file

Comment: Did you save the file after adding `\usepackage{tikz}`, before running `lualatex test.tex`? Because the code under your second update works fine here.

Comment: You need to enable shell escape. Your logs show `restricted system commands enabled`, but that is not enough.

Comment: The second error saying `\usetikzlibrary` is undefined cannot be from the code posted above it, as that code includes `\usepackage{tikz}`, which certainly defines this. I suggest editing your question to include only: (1) your current MWE and (2) your current error, produced when you compile with `lualatex --shell-escape` (or equivalent).

Comment: How stupid i am! The file has not been saved before i compile it in batch !!!! Thanks every body :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP forgot to save the updated file.